# scroll view set animation duration

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a scrollView with some text fields. when the keyboard show, the scroll view goes. When the keyboard is hidden the scroll view goes down. It works correctly. The only thing is that the keyboard takes 0.5 seconds to come up, so during that time I can see the white background. I would like to set a duration to my scroll3 to 0.5.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *)textField {
NSLog(@"sowing keyboard");
scroll3.frame = CGRectMake(0, -200, 768, 960);
[scroll3 scrollRectToVisible:scroll3.frame animated:YES];

}


-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"hiding keyboard");
scroll3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 960);
}
```

How can I?? I tried [scroll3 setAnimationDuration: 0.5]; but it does not work!!! Help ME Please!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this -

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
   [scroll3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -200, 768, 960)];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
 }

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField *)textField
 {

   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
   [scroll3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 960)];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `UIScrollView` manages its own animation you could try to set the `decelerationRate` to something higher so that the animation takes longer. I know that works for manual swipes, but I'm not sure if that also goes for automated swipes (when you set the visible rect). It's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible in your case you might just use an NSTimer.
This way you would not really change the duration of the animation but delay it a little bit
so that the background is not visible while the keyboard shows/hides.

This might look similar to the following code:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2] target:self 
    selector:@SEL(scrollMyScrollView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

This will call the given method after 0.2 seconds.
In the "scrollMyScrollView"-Method you do just what you do now.

Hope that helps ;)